# remix error while coding a smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm coding a contract and deploy it but REMIX gives me an error at this line and I can't understand why.

Line below

constructor (
address _client,
uint _duration,
uint _premium,
uint _payoutValue,
string _cropLocation,
address _link,
uint256 _oraclePaymentAmount);

```
payable Ownable() public
```

ERROR MESSAGE
ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function definition.
--> II Project.sol:72:1:
|
72 | constructor (

DO YOU KNOW WHAT IS WRONG WITH IT?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a function to should define it like this:

```
function Ownable() payable public{}
```

Comment: Hi Kasra, yes I did add it. Just didn't post it on here. It is still giving me the same error message. Any other solution?

Comment: @SmartBrick can you post your whole code?

Comment: Kasra, the error is on the mapping line. Soliduty version is ^0.4
mapping (address => InsuranceContract) contracts;

function newContract
(
    address _client,
    uint _duration,
    uint _premium,
    uint _payoutValue,
    string _cropLocation
) 
    
    public payable onlyOwner() returns(address)